# I have a 148 rep in meta, but can't login to the tavern to chat

Tags: support, chat, login

I can see my rep at the top of the page, so I'm logged in, but the bottom of the page says I have to be logged in to chat. There's no message entry box.

What am I doing wrong? This is my first time trying to chat (in a long time?).

Clicking on "logged in" just refreshes the page. I looked at a few similar questions, but couldn't see anything actionable. Tried the chat... url. That didn't work either.

Comment: When you are on http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/, does your name appear at the top of the screen? If not, you are not logged in.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS Everywhere?

Comment: Yes. I am. Do I have to turn it off for this site or something similar? I'll see if I can figure out how to do that selectively.

Comment: Yes, my name and 148 points appears on the top line.

Comment: @Emrakul Turned off SE partial rule in HTTPS Everywhere and chat window opened right up. Thanks. Solved. Post it as an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Comment: im having a similar problem but its with rep requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS Everywhere causes problems like these with some frequency around the web. Just remember that some sites weren't designed for HTTPS, and forcing them into it always has the possibility to break things.

Disable it for Stack Exchange, and you should be able to log in.