# Have 148 rep but getting 20 rep error message for chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat

I have found this question:

[I have a 148 rep in meta, but can't login to the tavern to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237667/i-have-a-148-rep-in-meta-but-cant-login-to-the-tavern-to-chat)

Which (oddly) lists the same rep, but I have no anonymizers installed as I am very careful about their use.

Why at 148 rep am I not allowed to talk in Shadow Wizard chat?
[image: Shadow Wizard Chat Bug]

Comment: Are you logged in to chat?

Comment: @Oded I'll try logging back in again now

Comment: Your chat profile was out of synch, either @Oded kicked it, or it resolved itself after you have re-login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resynced your chat profile. Seems OK now.

Comment: oded i'm having the same problem right now

Comment: @LittleBowsette - not much I can do about that. Not been an employee for well over 2 years. I suggest you open a new question.